Reviewer’s questions about the baseline analysis
Research Context:
I conducted a clinical study to explore the correlation between variable A and the incidence of heart disease, using a sample size of 4,000 individuals. The sample was divided into four groups (Q1-Q4) using the quartile method. During baseline analysis, for continuous variables, I applied the Kruskal-Wallis H test based on the normal or skewed distribution, and for categorical variables, I used the Chi-square test. The p-values for these tests were all less than 0.001.
Reviewer’s Concern:
The reviewer raised the following concern:
"All the baseline characteristics of individuals differ significantly (P<0.001) among the Q1-Q4 quartiles of A. Therefore, there seems to be a large initial bias in the representation of CVD risk factors among these subgroups."
Questions:
1.How should I respond to the reviewer’s comment?
2.Should I consider changing my statistical methods, or are these methods appropriate for addressing this issue?

Was your study randomised in any way? What exactly did you look at post-baseline?

My approach is as follows: a total of 4200 patients were categorized into four groups (Q1-Q4) based on the quartile distribution of the continuous variable A. The visual binning method provided by SPSS was used.

First, do not discretize A into four (or two, or thirty-seven) groups. This loses information for absolutely zero benefit. For instance, it treats everyone in the first group as identical on A, but completely different from everyone in the second group, although two people in the first group might differ far more on A than one person each from groups 1 and 2.
Instead, treat A as a numerical variable, and actually do use a correlation analysis (Pearson, Spearman, Kendall, as appropriate), or ANCOVA if you have more covariates.
Now, your reviewer writes that

All the baseline characteristics of individuals differ significantly (P<0.001) among the Q1-Q4 quartiles of A.

This is an issue, because now you can't say that any difference in the outcome is driven by A or by these characteristics. It's quite hard to "control for" covariates that differ between groups (I like to recommend Miller & Chapman, 2001). If you follow my advice above, dispense with the grouping and use A as a numerical covariate, then it is equally hard to disentangle the effects of correlated covariates.
You may be able to use something like a PCA to extract common variability between your covariates. Alternatively, something like a moderator-mediator analysis may be indicated. It will depend on the actual biological mechanisms at work here.

I have a different read on the reviewer's comments.  Their concern is that "baseline characteristics"--strong candidates for covariates in a model--also differ among the quartiles of $A,$ and therefore the analysis ought to control for those differences.  If not, then any variation in risk among the quartiles of the $A$ values cannot be attributed to $A.$

@whuber: very good point, I misread the question. Have edited heavily (so later readers may not understand your point any more unless they look at the edit history).
